# subtract vloopup result value in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to subtract two value which I got from 2 different vlookup formula

here is my code:

`Salary="=VLOOKUP(" & Target.Address(False, False) & ",LookupValues!A:J,10,FALSE)"`

`ASA = "=VLOOKUP(" & Target.Address(False, False) & ",LookupValues!A:K,11,FALSE)"`

`Target.Offset(0, 7).Formula = Salary - ASA`

When I try to subtract Salary - ASA I got error

**Run type erroe 13 Type mismatch**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one instead:

```
Salary = "VLOOKUP(" & target.Address(False, False) & ",LookupValues!A:J,10,FALSE)"
ASA = "VLOOKUP(" & target.Address(False, False) & ",LookupValues!A:K,11,FALSE)"
target.Offset(0, 7).Formula = "=" & Salary & "-" & ASA
```

You got `Run type erroe 13 Type mismatch` because you tried substract *string* from *string*, i.e. `"string1"-"string2"`. And also note that I've removed `=` in your `Salary` and `ASA` (with `=` sign you'd get wrong formula `=VLOOKUP(..)-=VLOOKUP(..)`